# How to add a note or link a domain to database in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm working with a hosting and when I access to phpmyadmin I can see:
[Example to be replicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkQtn.png)

*"db8u378c7ngkae (exampledomainname.com)"*
I want to know what is that info showed between the characters '(' and ')', and how can I replicate that on other phpmyadmin.

Phpmyadmin info:

- MySQL
- Version: 5.7.32-35
- Protocol Version: 10

Answer (score 0):

Is the part in the parentheses not part of the actual database name? You could run a query from the SQL tab, `show databases like 'db8u%';` and report the result back here for further analysis.

If it's not part of the name, I'm not certain, but wonder if that could be a comment. You can check easily by clicking on the database name (db8u378c7ngkae), then going to the Operations tab. The comment is shown in the first field, "Database comment" so if that field already has "exampledomainname.com" entered in when you load the page, that will be what the navigation pane is showing you. My database comments don't display like that (it's a "mouseover" popup), but that's my next best guess.

Once you determine how it's happening on the first machine, we can figure out how to replicate the behavior on the second one.